# Append new <li> and increase its ID number by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, html-lists

So I'm trying to append a new `<li>` and increase its ID number by 1 every time so I end up having something like:

```
    <ul id="bxs"> 

                <li id="item-1">1</li> 
                <li id="item-2">2</li> 
                <li id="item-3">3</li> 
                <li id="item-4">4</li> 
                <li id="item-5">5</li> 
                <li id="item-6">6</li> 
</ul>
```

This is what my jQuery looks like:

```
var itemCount = 1;
$(function() {

    $("#NewItem").click(function(e) {  // NewItem is my button
            e.preventDefault();
            itemCount++;
        var element = $("<li id="item-" + itemCount>" + itemCount + "</li>");
        $("#bxs").append(element);
    });
});
```

What I'm I doing wrong? There must be something wrong on where I add the itemCount in the div. I tried this as well: `<li id="item-" + itemCount + ">` but doesn't work either.

Can someone guide me please?

Comment: Place itemCount = 1; inside the anonymous function instead

Comment: Seeing the 'broken' output would be helpful. Just a note, though: it will be more flexible to count the existing number of "#bxs li" items instead of initializing and keeping an itemCount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your not concatenating your string properly. You should be using single quotes inside your double quotes. In addition, you can't set `itemCount = 1` if you already have existing items. I suggest setting `itemCount` dynamically. See example below (and fiddle).

```
$(function() {    
    $("#NewItem").click(function(e) {  // NewItem is my button
            e.preventDefault();
        var itemCount = ($("[id^='item-']").length + 1);
        var element = $("<li id='item-" + itemCount + "'>" + itemCount + "</li>");
        $("#bxs").append(element);
    });
});
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/zneMq/).

Comment: Why are you using the jQuery function $() to piece together the HTML to be inserted into the DOM? Isn't that really intended to be used for selecting elements, not creating raw HTML code? Didn't know if there was some benefit to this over simple string concatenation.

Comment: @Todd: The `$()` function can select DOM elements, but it can also create DOM elements.  `$('<div><div/>')` creates a new div element, and returns a jQuery object containing it.

Comment: Yes, which is why the fiddle works, but just seemed like overkill since there's no manipulation happening on the newly created element itself (in which case I would see the benefit of using $() to create it). I guess it's just a choice of style? :)

Comment: @Todd: Not sure if it's faster to have `element` be a string or a jQuery object.

Comment: @Rocket, it is hugely faster to hold a string and concat to it then do a single build through a jquery object at the end than to build an object every time. For small use cases like this though the difference between his and using a string is negligent.

Comment: @JamesHill can you tell me why this: http://jsfiddle.net/h3ZSr/6/ doesn't work? Try add a new item and click on it. Shouldn't it alert?

Comment: @jQuerybeast, you need to use the `.live()` function to handle dynamically added items - http://jsfiddle.net/VjADM/1/. I'm heading out for a few hours so this will be my last reply :)

Comment: live will be deprecated on jquery 1.8 so I suppose that is not a solution.

Answer (score 3):

try this...

```
var element = $("<li id='item-" + itemCount +"'>" + itemCount + "</li>");
```

Comment: You forgot the `+"` between `itemCount` and `'>`.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using $( in front of the HTML code?

```
var element = '<li id="item-' + itemCount+ '">' + itemCount + '</li>';
```

Think this does the trick

Comment: You *should* quote your HTML attributes.

Answer (score 2):

That is a a weird string, try using single quotes fro your string instead;

```
var element = $('<li id="item-' + itemCount + '">' + itemCount + '</li>');
```

Comment: Thanks alot. I choosed James answer because it feels better to avoid the variable which I didn't knew I could do.

Answer (score 1):

```
var element = $("<li id="item-" + itemCount>" + itemCount + "</li>");
```

needs to be

```
var element = '<li id="item-' + itemCount + '">' + itemCount + '</li>';
```

Comment: You have your attribute quotes mixed up, that would produce `<li id="item-"5>"5"</li>"`.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for catching that. Edited it just now.

Answer (score 1):

I always opt to use the API when possible. It saves issues like this.

```
var element = $("<li></li>", { id: "item-" + itemCount }).html(itemCount);
```

Comment: Some browsers (ie. IE) prefer `$("<li></li>")` to `$("<li>")`.

Comment: Usually I use <li />. It was a typo for me to leave off the /.